# [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired - Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I have 2 projects (A and B), the project A using Laravel 5.4 and connecting in a database instance from mssql (this database is to my development environment). The project B use Laravel 5.7 and cannot connect in the same instance, I get this return:

```
"SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

But both projects can connect in production without problems. I use the same database confs for project A and B.

I running a docker container and the Dockerfile is the same for both projects. I can't undestand why in one works, but in another no.

I'm using php 7.1

Production Conf:

```
'database_test' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'sqlsrv.xxxxx.com.br'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user_database'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'user_password'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'options' => [
        ],
```

Development Conf:

```
'database_test' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '99.000.000.99\MBC03'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user_database'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'user_password'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'options' => [
        ],
    ],
```